# Refresh table with newly added data

Tags: javascript, html

My table data are populated dynamically upon my page loads. It now has this `no data available` showing up. How do I sort of refresh the table?

I have tried the `table.DataTable()` method but to no avail.
[image]

Comment: You will have to create a markup and set it as HTML. Also are you using any plugin for table?

Comment: @Rajesh I am using some bootstrap theme. I tried placing my `.js` to fetch   the table data before calling the plugin `.js` but to no avail too.